# Create String of Comma Separated Quotes from List

Tags: c#, list

I have a class called user that contains a list of groups that are strings ( Group A, Group B, Group C)

```
public class User
    {

        public string FirstName { get; set; }
        public string LastName { get; set; }

        public User()
        {
            Groups = new List<string>();
        }

    }
```

I am then using a json deserializer to create the list of users and groups. However I would like to be able to get a string of the groups with this format for each user:

"Group A", "Group B", "Group C"

I have tried this:

```
string[] AllGroups;
AllGroups = (string[])usrList[0].Groups.ToArray();
return string.Join(",", AllGroups);
```

However it is giving me a list in this format (with no quotes):

Group A, Group B, Group C

Any idea what I  am doing wrong here?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

> Any idea what I am doing wrong here?

Well you're not adding the quotes anywhere - so you're not getting them.

You can surround each item with quotes yourself easily enough:

```
return string.Join(", ", usrList[0].Groups.Select(x => "\"" + x + "\""));
```

That's assuming you're using .NET 4 or higher - if you're using .NET 3.5 (which doesn't have quite as good `string.Join` support) you need to create an array, but you don't need to cast it to `string[]` (as `ToArray` already returns an array)...

```
return string.Join(", ", usrList[0].Groups
                                   .Select(x => "\"" + x + "\"")
                                   .ToArray());
```

I've added a space after the comma delimiter as well, given your question - I suspect your current code is *really* giving you `Group A,Group B,Group C`.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you want to get `""` as a result when there are no values, you can do this:

```
 return "\"" + string.Join("\", \"", AllGroups) + "\"";
```

Note that this is **not** an empty string - it's a string which contains two quotes.

If you want to return null or the empty string using this code, you'd need to check the size of `AllGroups` first.

```
var AllGroups = usrList[0].Groups;
if (AllGroups.Count() == 0) return null;
else return "\"" + string.Join("\", \"", AllGroups) + "\"";
```